# Python timedelta with seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

On the doc it says for `timedelta(seconds= )`, the seconds should be `Between 0 and 86399 inclusive`. However I hope to pass a parameter with `timedelta(seconds=432000)` (5 days in seconds. I understand we can pass `days = 5` but it was preferred for the parma to be written in seconds. It is larger than 86399 but in console when I tested, it was still resolved to days. Is it ok to pass in seconds like this ? Many thanks for your help.

```
nowtime = datetime.now()
print(nowtime)
2021-06-24 15:08:36.048664
plusdays = timedelta (seconds = 432000) 
print(nowtime+plusdays)
2021-06-29 15:08:36.048664
```

Comment: If the documentation says the max is 86399, you're taking a chance if you use anything larger.  It could stop working tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs don't say that ;-) They say that only days, seconds, and microseconds are *stored* internally, and are normalized in such a way that the internal seconds stored is in `range(86400)`.

So far as what you can pass to the constructor, just about anything is fine; e.g., even negative seconds:

```py
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta(hours=1, seconds=-1)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3599)
```

### Example

`time.time()` generally returns the number of seconds since 1970 began (the "Unix epoch"). That can be used directly to convert to and from a UTC datetime.

```py
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> now = time.time(); datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 24, 21, 51, 27, 939029)
>>> now
1624571487.9390297
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=now)
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 24, 21, 51, 27, 939030)
```

The final output is within a microsecond of when `utcnow()` was called.

Comment: Thanks but could you elaborate a bit? I was referring to this page and it says `If the normalized value of days lies outside the indicated range, OverflowError is raised.`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: Which says nothing about seconds, right? It says days. All inputs are converted to a mix of (only) microseconds, seconds and days; microsecond and seconds are normalized to force them into the documented ranges, which can cause "carries" into the next higher time unit (microseconds -> seconds, and seconds -> days), and _then_ if the final number of days is outside the documented range for days, `OverflowError` is raised.